# How to get IP Address of Docker Desktop VM?

Tags: docker-desktop

I'm in a team where some of us use docker toolbox and some user docker desktop. We're writing an application that needs to communicate to a docker container in development.

On docker toolbox, I know the docker-machine env command sets the docker host environment variable and I can use that to get the ip of the virtual machine that's running the docker engine. From there I just access the exposed ports.

What's the equivalent way to get that information on docker desktop? (I do not have a machine that has docker desktop, only docker toolbox but I'm writing code that should be able to access the docker container on both)

Answer (score 25):

On windows OS, after installed docker, there is an entry added by docker inside your hosts file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts), which states the IP as:

## Added by Docker Desktop

10.xx.xx.xx host.docker.internal

Comment: I found (Docker 19.03.8) multiple entries in my hosts file, unfortunately the default resolutor did not pick the right one and I had to set it manually. It is dynamically allocated so it may change. If you know the exposed port you may run netstat -na to find the real ip address you should use.

Comment: I get `127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal`

Comment: @Pathros - on Windows, If you have Docker Desktop installed, a few lines above that you should see a line for `host.docker.internal`.

Answer (score 4):

Below section got added in my /etc/hosts:

```
# Added by Docker Desktop
192.168.99.1 host.docker.internal
192.168.99.1 gateway.docker.internal
```

Then I was able to access by adding the port to which the app was bind to.

Answer (score 0):

This command should display the IP

```
ping -q -c 1 docker.local | sed -En "s/^.*\((.+)\).*$/\1/p"
```

Comment: Is there another way to do this? The code that I'm writing is not going to be able to ping. Also, is there a way to get the container accessible on the localhost?

Comment: On docker, you can always expose ports to expose services on the container to the host machine. Also, as of version 18.03, you can use `host.docker.internal` as the host's IP.

Comment: I'm talking from the host machine and not inside the container. Thank you for the replies.

Comment: I only get a two digit number. What does it mean?

Comment: Mac: "ping: cannot resolve docker.local: Unknown host"

Answer (score -1):

ipconfig can get you this information as well

Comment: Kind of true as "ping host.docker.internal" (on Windows) actually gives out your WLAN IP, and on ipconfig you can see another VEthernet connection IP which also maps to Docker